# How do I target the Angular active tab with CSS?

Tags: css, angular, tabs

So I have some Angular tabs with icons, I want the active tab icon to be different than the inactive ones. I see the active tab has a class of "mdc-tab--active" and the inactive tabs have a class of "mat-mdc-tab-disabled" but for some reason my CSS does not get applied.

With tabs like this, for example:

```
<mat-tab [disabled]=false>
<ng-template mat-tab-label>
<mat-icon class="example-tab-icon lockopen">lock_open</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="example-tab-icon lockclosed">lock</mat-icon>
Title
</ng-template>
<ng-container>
Contents
</ng-container>
</mat-tab>

<mat-tab [disabled]=true>
<ng-template mat-tab-label>
<mat-icon class="example-tab-icon lockopen">lock_open</mat-icon>
<mat-icon class="example-tab-icon lockclosed">lock</mat-icon>
Title
</ng-template>
<ng-container>
Contents
</ng-container>
</mat-tab>
```

Why can I not just do this CSS and show/hide the correct icons:

```
.mdc-tab--active .lockclosed{
display:none;
}
.mat-mdc-tab-disabled .lockopen{
display:none;
}
```

The CSS does not get applied, I am assuming (guessing) because the active and disabled classes for Angular tabs are being added dynamically so the CSS can't target the elements right on page load?

If I just do a normal ".lockopen{display:none;}" it does hide an icon, so I know the targeting is correct and the CSS should work, but doesn't.

The active tab will always be changing so I can't add my own classes to the tabs, I need to use the ones Angular creates to determine if a tab is active or not, but they don't seem to work.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Angular generated CSS are scoped to that particular component so they cannot target children (unless we use something like the deprecated [ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep)). The generated css styles look something like this:

```
.mdc-tab--active[_ngcontent-yfi-c543] .lockopen[_ngcontent-yfi-c543] {/* your styles */}
```

The actual element with the class `.mdc-tab--active` may not be having the `_ngcontent` attribute, so the styles aren't getting applied.

From your code snipped it looks like you're using material components from angular. The examples in their docs suggest using `<mat-tab>` inside `<mat-tab-group>`. `<mat-tab-group>` supports a 2-way binding for the selected index. Using a mix of that and ng-templates to reduce duplication we could have something like this:

```
<mat-tab-group [(selectedIndex)]="activeIndex">
  <mat-tab>
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <ng-container
        *ngTemplateOutlet="tabIcon; context: {active: activeIndex === 0}"
      ></ng-container>
      First
    </ng-template>
    Content 1
  </mat-tab>

  <mat-tab isActive="true">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <ng-container
        *ngTemplateOutlet="tabIcon; context: {active: activeIndex === 1}"
      ></ng-container>
      Second
    </ng-template>
    Content 2
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<ng-template #tabIcon let-active="active">
  <mat-icon
    class="example-tab-icon"
    [ngClass]="{'example-tab-icon-rotated': active}"
    >thumb_up</mat-icon
  >
</ng-template>
```

The above code is a modified version of an example found in the Angular Material docs.

[Working stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-i6hmaq?file=app%2Ftab-group-custom-label-example.html)

If you have the list of tabs available as a variable inside the component, you could even make the code more concise by looping over the tabs instead of manually passing the condition like `activeIndex === 1` for every tab